# Minesweeper C++

Tags: c++, minesweeper

I've written the minesweeper game for C++, and the core game is complete.

There are three things I need to ask.

1. Currently, my mines are placed at random positions.. I was wondering if this is true for the actual game? Are the mines random or is their some specific pattern or algorithm for placing the mines.
2. When I play minesweeper on Win 7, I never see a 0. But in my program, there are cases when all 8 neighbors are non mines. What should I display then? I want the game to be as close to the Windows version as possible.
3. I think this may be related to 2 above, when I play on Win 7 sometimes when I click on a cell multiple cells are revealed. I want to do this in my program but I don't know the controlling logic behind it. I mean, when does this have to happen? And when it does happen, how do I know how many and which cells to open up?

On a related note, my current program is text based (in code blocks). Currently I know only C++. What do I need to learn to be able to make the game interactive?

Comment: 2=3: when you click on a 0 in Windows it automatically clicks on all of the squares around it for you, which may include other 0s and so cascade on.

Comment: Sorry but SO is not the good place to ask that.

Comment: The mines are randomly placed in the original game. (Of course, they are really pseudo-randomly placed, which means that there is a specific algorithm at play here, but that is just a side effect of the implementation)

Comment: To make it interactive you can use the widespread Qt that is nice to build user interface.

Comment: Also (at least this used to be the case), the code is made so that if your first guess is a mine, then it is automatically changed to a non-mine square and the mine moved elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you are new here. Please do not ask multiple questions in one question; prefer to click the "Ask Question"-button multiple times instead :) Other than that, you might want to read the Tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: This question appears to be a better fit on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't fit for your question, try asking on Game Development (gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MagnusHoff Multiple questions are allowed in one question on Stack Overflow, but however they must be closely related. See the Meta post (more like 'argument') on this.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I got my answer and yes, I am new to this. First question, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes they are placed at random.  You need to make sure that you don't place two mines in the same spot.
2. A 0 is displayed as a blank in windows.
3. When you expose a square with no adjacent mines, it will automatically expose all 8 of those squares.  If any of those are also zeros, they will be exposed also until an entire region is exposed.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first guess is never a mine, so your generation algorithm must delay itself until this happens. As far as I am aware, mines are placed pseudo randomly.
2. When no adjacent mines are found on a guessed square, it reveals all adjacent squares.
3. On the versions I have played, when you left click and then right click together and when a location has a sufficient number of flags placed around it, it reveals all adjacent squares.